# How to access environment variables in a .js file in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I have the following files:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
import { locales } from './services/i18n'
...
    i18n: {
        lazy: true,
        langDir: '~/locales/',
        defaultLocale: 'en',
        detectBrowserLanguage: false,
        differentDomains: true,
        locales,
        vueI18n: {
            fallbackLocale: 'en'
        }
    },
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
        ...
        subDomain: process.env.SUB_DOMAIN,
    },
...
```

---

```js
// services/i18n/index.js
export const locales = [
    {
        code: 'ar',
        iso: 'ar',
        file: 'ar.json',
        dir: 'rtl',
        domain: `${process.env.SUB_DOMAIN}.example.ae`,
        name: 'العَرَبِيَّة',
        enName: 'Arabic',
        defaultLanguage: true,
        languages: ['ar']
    },
    {
        code: 'bg',
        iso: 'bg',
        file: 'bg.json',
        dir: 'ltr',
        domain: `${process.env.SUB_DOMAIN}.example.bg`,
        name: 'Български',
        enName: 'Bulgarian',
        defaultLanguage: true,
        languages: ['bg']
    },
    ...
]
```

The problem is that `process.env.SUB_DOMAIN` seems to be undefined in `/services/i18n/index.js`, although it is set because the same variable is not undefined in `nuxt.config.js`. I know that nuxt is exposing the values of `publicRuntimeConfig` as `$config`, however, `$config` is not accessible in `/services/i18n/index.js`. It might work if I would move `locales` to `nuxt.config.js`, but I don't want to do that because it would worsen the readability of the config file.

So my **question** is what the best approach would be to get subdomain inside `/services/i18n/index.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: A great answer was given on Nuxtjs' discussions by Alexander Lichter: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/discussions/9289#discussioncomment-729801

```js
// nuxt.config.js
import { locales } from './services/i18n'
...
    i18n: {
        lazy: true,
        langDir: '~/locales/',
        defaultLocale: 'en',
        detectBrowserLanguage: false,
        differentDomains: true,
        locales: locales(process.env.SUB_DOMAIN),
        vueI18n: {
            fallbackLocale: 'en'
        }
    },
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
        ...
        subDomain: process.env.SUB_DOMAIN,
    },
...
```

```js
// services/i18n/index.js
export const locales = domain => [
    {
        code: 'ar',
        iso: 'ar',
        file: 'ar.json',
        dir: 'rtl',
        domain: `${domain}.example.ae`,
        name: 'العَرَبِيَّة',
        enName: 'Arabic',
        defaultLanguage: true,
        languages: ['ar']
    },
    {
        code: 'bg',
        iso: 'bg',
        file: 'bg.json',
        dir: 'ltr',
        domain: `${domain}.example.bg`,
        name: 'Български',
        enName: 'Bulgarian',
        defaultLanguage: true,
        languages: ['bg']
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: Maybe try to ask this question on the new related github discussions here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/discussions

Comment: How would you suggest doing this with the file you just want to share env with

for example, I have a constant.js file

export const BASE_URL =  process.env.BASE_URL
my process.env is undefined but in nuxt.config they are all there and I can use them across plugins, middlewares, and so on

Comment: @rrrm93 a full brand new question with some details would be welcome here!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75940172/nuxt-how-to-access-env-in-javascript-files posted