# nuxt how to access env in javascript files

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, nuxt.js

I cant access my env variables outside nuxt 2.15, When I deploy I can see `$nuxt.context.$config` in the browser has the correct variables, but on custom js file I cant access `process.env.baseURL` it returns undefined

```js
// nuxt.config.ts
module.exports = {
  ssr: false,
  buildModules: [  
    ['@nuxtjs/dotenv', { systemvars: true }],
  ],
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    baseURL: process.env.baseURL,
  }
  env: {
    baseURL: process.env.baseURL,
  }
}
```

This works fine accross pages/components/middleware I can access the values using the $config object

The problem is I have a JS file where i want to import value of baseURL to use in other places and this comes back as undefined

```js
//constant.ts

const { publicRuntimeConfig, env } = require('./nuxt.config.ts');
const { baseURL, VPN_IP, ADMIN_MODE } = publicRuntimeConfig;

console.info('constant: baseURL', baseURL); // also undefined

export const GRPC_HOST = process.env.baseURL;  //this is undefined
```

I have tried changing the start command from `nuxt start` to `node server/index.ts`

```js
const express = require('express');
const consola = require('consola');
require('dotenv').config();
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt');
const app = express();

// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
const config = require('../nuxt.config.ts');
config.dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

async function start() {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt({ ...config, env: { baseURL: process.env.baseURL } });

  const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server;

  await nuxt.ready();
  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt);
    await builder.build();
  }

  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render);

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host);
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on https://${host}:${port} , environment:: ${process.env.NODE_ENV} baseURL:: ${process.env.baseURL}`,
    badge: true,
  });
}
start();
```

On the server logs I can see baseURL is set here NODE_ENV is set to production

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a javascript file with the `$config`. First, you need to make sure you have imported the $config object correctly. You could use `window.$nuxt.$config` with the variables,

try this:

```js
const baseURL = window.$nuxt.$config.baseURL
console.info('constant: baseURL', baseURL)
export const GRPC_HOST = baseURL
```

Comment: had to use onLoad to check if dom was ready, technically it works but it adds a couple of seconds delay until the initial load is ready,